# Shell Scripting replace string with variable linux

Tags: linux, string, shell, replace

I am trying to replace string like "c:\abacd" with a variable containing ex. v_var="e:\abcd" in shell scripting. but below code is not working.

sed -i "s+c:\abcd+${v_var}+g" ~/test.txt

but, i am successfully able to replace other simple words like "test" with variable containing v_rest="rest" in a file using cmd below. i am using variable

sed -i "s+test+${v_rest}+g" ~/test.txt

Comment: try escaping the \ char with \\

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
export v_var="e:\\\\abcd"
sed -i "s/c:\\\\abcd/${v_var}/g" ~/test.txt
```

You need to escape the '\' in the command-line and variable.